# android - dual pane view with indicator for selected list item

Tags: android-layout, android

In my application I have a dual-pane layout with a list on the left side. I would like to add an indicator at the right of the selected list row, as in the following examples:

[image: Gmail example]
[image: Reader example]

I assume it is a built-in function, but I couldn't find any documentation on it. Does anyone knows how we implement this ?

Comment: Can you show code on how you achieved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having a look at the code, I couldn't say for sure, but I'm pretty certain that the indicator is *not* a built-in feature. It might be a custom view, but most likely they just set a compound drawable, as is described here:
[BitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) and here: [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

The method you are looking for is setCompoundDrawables().

Comment: Thanks for the clue, it seems like a good guess of what they might have used. I'll try to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, i would just add the indicator matching the color of the right sides background, making it look seamless. Simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it, is to use a [9-patch image](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch). For example, if you want to reproduce the effect of the dual-pane with Theme.DeviceDefault.Light (API > 14), use a [Selector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)  to apply your 9-patch background image in Selected state of your LinearLayout item.

Example of a selectable item layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="48dp"
android:background="@drawable/activable_indicator_background"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingRight="20dp">
    //eventually other items...
</LinearLayout>
```

`Drawable/activable_indicator_background.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/indicator" /> 
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

`Drawable/indicator.9.png`:

[image: Indicator 9-patch image]